# Auto serial number and text in Google Sheets: "Number - Text" by dragging

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, concatenation, string-formatting, textjoin

For my data project, column A is Name of "number-text".

Google Sheets can automatically create "text-number" by dragging.

ABC - 01

ABC - 02

ABC - 03

But it doesn’t work when I use: "number - text" .

Example:

01 - ABC

02 - ABC

03 - ABC

How can I create a serial number and text in Google Sheets by dragging or another better solution (arrayformula)?

Comment: Rather than presenting a small, abstract example out of context, you may get more help if you instead explain your real-world problem, i.e., what you are trying to do, exactly, why you want to do that and when/how that should happen. (BTW, I am not the one who marked your post down.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wish for a dragging solution, you can try:

```
=TEXT(ROW(A1), "00")&" - ABC"
```

[image]

Though, the proper way would be to use arrayformula bound to another column, like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,TEXT(COUNTIFS(B2:B, "<>",
 ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B)), "00")&" - ABC"))
```

[image]