# Serial "number - text" by dragging auto created with TEXT formula

Tags: google-sheets

Related topic: *[Auto serial number and text in google sheet: "Number - Text" by dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845612/auto-serial-number-and-text-in-google-sheet-number-text-by-dragging/67849267#67849267)*

Formula from player0:

```
=TEXT(ROW(A1), "00")&" - ABC"
```

This formula gets a number of rows, like in column C in the attached image.

I want to the get "number of cell" in column A", like in column B.

How can I calculate it?

Please see the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=TEXT(ROW(), "00")&" - ABC"
```

and see if that helps?

Comment: As a reference, see [ROW function (Google Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en) for more information.